# Installed ADT eclipse plugin with no result

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

Eclipse version is Kepler and compiles with jdk 1.7. I installed the ADT plugin using Help->Install new software-> add https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/. It seemed to install successfully.

When eclipse was restarted, I was not prompted to specify the location of the android sdk as expected in the adk installation tutorial.

None of the ADT options/tools (sdk manager, device manager, option to make android projects) exist in eclipse, yet the ADT appears to be installed:

[image: Installation details]

How can I use the ADT features like device manager etc in my copy of eclipse?

Comment: go to window -> preferences and see if you have android option on the left pane. There you can config your sdk path

Comment: Looks like there's no android section in the preferences